# Give a symbol an alphabetical "order"?

Tags: indexing, alphabet

I've defined a `C++` symbol in latex as `\CC`, which works fine:

```
\newcommand{\CC}{C\nolinebreak\hspace{-.05em}\raisebox{.4ex}{\tiny\bf +}\nolinebreak\hspace{-.10em}\raisebox{.4ex}{\tiny\bf +}}
```

However, I'd also like to include it in my index. I'm currently just using `\index{\CC}`, but this puts the entry for `C++` at the start of the index (presumably because it's a symbol):

[image: C++ appearing first in index]

I'd like to instead preserve the alphabetical order of the C in the index. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Try `\index{C++@\CC}`

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Thanks, that did the trick! If you post as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override the default sort key using the `@` specifier:

```
\index{C++@\CC}
```

This tells `makeindex` to sort according to `C++` but to use `\CC` in the index.

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify this repetitive indexing by redefining your C++-command:

```
\newcommand{\CC}{%
  C\nolinebreak\hspace{-.05em}\raisebox{.4ex}{\tiny\bf +}%
  \nolinebreak\hspace{-.10em}\raisebox{.4ex}{\tiny\bf +}%
  \index{C++@\protect\CC}}
```

Then you will just write `\CC` and have it indexed every time.

Comment: That'll save you keystrokes, but, depending on the type of document, it may sacrifice the quality of the index a bit.